# Desktop Computer not starting up after installation of Wireless Card

Tags: motherboard, power, desktop-computer

I'm walking my friend through installing a Wireless Card in his computer that I just built him, but for some reason it isn't booting.

I've tried unplugging, holding power button for 30 seconds, plugging it back in turning it on with no luck

I've told him to make sure the power supply is on and even had him plug directly into the wall in case it was a surge protector issue

I him uninstall the wifi card and try again, no luck.

I had him swap out the power cord for another cord to see if it would work, nada.

He does not see any lights on the mobo, but from what I can remember from my old mobo there weren't any lights on there. He does notice his mouse is on, though. it is plugged directly into the mobo via USB.

Any ideas what could be wrong? I really hope the PSU I just bought didnt go out, that would be really unfortunate :(

Comment: Does the PC have integrated graphics or does it use a dedicated GPU?

Comment: it uses a Dedicated GPU

Comment: I know it may sound silly, but I've had friends who have plugged their video connector to the onboard video instead of the GPU and therefore couldn't get any video from their PC. Have your friend make sure the monitor is plugged into the GPU and not the onboard graphics (if the PC has it).

Comment: Also not likely (but I have seen it), the wireless card may have been inserted slightly off shorting out the PSU. You need to take a look at the PC yourself as it is really difficult to pinpoint the reason otherwise.

Comment: Okay he said yes it is in the GPU. The largest issues I'm seeing is that it is straight up not booting other than power to the mouse. I am starting to think it may be the PSU being shorted out unfortunately. I will have to drive to his house (2 and a half hours away, yikes lol) and see if I can figure it out. Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried removing the Wifi Card and seeing if it boots then?

Comment: Yes I have DrZoo

Comment: Maybe something got knocked loose during install of the card.

Comment: Hopefully he didn't install the Wifi card when the PC was powered on...? Usually the biggest culprit is RAM being loose when this happens. Might want to re-seat them.

Comment: I traveled out to his house to see the issues, and unfortunately the mobo was fried! No worries though, I hooked him up with a nice upgrade (Ryzen 5 2600x, new mobo, 16gb 3200 ram). Thank you all for the advice!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the motherboard was fried.